# Location detecting techniques for IP addresses

Tags: http, geolocation

What are the location detecting techniques for IP addresses?
I know to look at the
`$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE']` (not accurate but mostly useful to detect location, for example if an IP range's users set French to their browser then it means that this range) belongs to France
and
`gethostbyaddr($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])` (to look country code top-level domain)
then may be to whois `gethostbyaddr($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])`
sometimes:
`$HTTP_USER_AGENT` (Firefox's user agent string has language code, not accurate but mostly can be used to detect the location)

Also I know how to get the time zone but it does not work in the new browsers.
Moreover there is [css issue](http://hacks.mozilla.org/2010/03/privacy-related-changes-coming-to-css-vistited/) that detects visitor's history, it can be used to see what google and wikipedia pages he/she has visited (google.co.uk, google.com.tr)

But what about cities?

Comment: Multiple duplicates, including http://stackoverflow.com/questions/283016/know-a-good-ip-address-geolocation-service and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2244989/need-a-client-side-api-for-determing-geo-location-of-ip-addresses

Comment: No, they ask for services, I ask how those services have detected the locations.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can't do this without a database that maps IP addresses to cities/countries/providers. There are commercial offerings such as [ip2location](http://www.ip2location.com/) that you could use. <s>AFAIK there is no free alternative though, as maintaining such a IP database is quite a lot of work.</s> Free alternative: [GeoIP2](http://search.cpan.org/dist/GeoIP2/)

**Update:**
There are several things that allow you to create such a db, if you invest enough time:

1. Use the databases provided by [regional and local registries](http://www.iana.org/numbers/) to find an IP's owner.
2. Many ISPs use a naming schema that allows you to locate the user. Sometimes you can
   even read the city name in plain text if you do a reverse-DNS lookup. Sometimes it is
   more cryptic. For example I currently have p5dcf6c4a.dip.t-dialin.net , and I have no 
   idea that the naming scheme is..
3. Use a traceroute. If you can't identify the location of a user, you can still find out
   the location of its uplink

Comment: Yes, I know them but I want to learn how do they make their own database.

Comment: FWIW, 5dcf6c4a was probably your IP address. Split it up by hex byte and convert to decimal: 5d.df.6c.4a -> 93.223.108.74. Sometimes the segments are reversed.

Answer (score 5):

If you looking for some copy - paste solution, i foudn this code :

```
    function countryCityFromIP($ipAddr)
{
//function to find country and city from IP address
//Developed by Roshan Bhattarai http://roshanbh.com.np

//verify the IP address for the
ip2long($ipAddr)== -1 || ip2long($ipAddr) === false ? trigger_error("Invalid IP", E_USER_ERROR) : "";
$ipDetail=array(); //initialize a blank array

//get the XML result from hostip.info
$xml = file_get_contents("http://api.hostip.info/?ip=".$ipAddr);

//get the city name inside the node <gml:name> and </gml:name>
preg_match("@<Hostip>(\s)*<gml:name>(.*?)</gml:name>@si",$xml,$match);

//assing the city name to the array
$ipDetail['city']=$match[2]; 

//get the country name inside the node <countryName> and </countryName>
preg_match("@<countryName>(.*?)</countryName>@si",$xml,$matches);

//assign the country name to the $ipDetail array
$ipDetail['country']=$matches[1];

//get the country name inside the node <countryName> and </countryName>
preg_match("@<countryAbbrev>(.*?)</countryAbbrev>@si",$xml,$cc_match);
$ipDetail['country_code']=$cc_match[1]; //assing the country code to array

//return the array containing city, country and country code
return $ipDetail;

}
```

Hope this helps somebody.

Answer (score 4):

You can map an IP address to its location (city, country, postal code), timezone etc. with either a database or an API (hosted database).

Here's an example of using an API

```
curl https://ipapi.co/city/ 
> Mountain View

curl https://ipapi.co/country/
> US

curl https://ipapi.co/timezone/
> America/Los_Angeles
```

more here : [Location from IP address](https://ipapi.co/api/#specific-location-field)

Answer (score 2):

U can use this function

```
 function ip_info(){
            return $data = json_decode(file_get_contents('http://ip-api.com/json/'),true);
        }
```

Call the function

```
$info = ip_info();
var_dump($info);
```

Comment: How do you pass an ip address to this function other than your current IP address?  I am recording the IP address when someone enters data in a form, I only want to verify users who are entering spam or junk

Comment: @KimWilson see my answer below

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using third party API I would suggest you to use self hosted IP record. This post explain you more

http://www.techsirius.com/2014/05/simple-geo-tracking-system.html

Basically they are using maxmind's country city IP database record [http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/geoip2/geolite2/] with few modifications. After that a sample query

```
$ip =  $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$long = sprintf('%u', ip2long($ip));
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `geo_ips` WHERE '$long' BETWEEN `ip_start` AND `ip_end`";
```

Answer (score 0):

One way in which these databases are compiled is from whois information.  For example, to determine the location of 69.59.196.211:

> fmark@home:~$ host 69.59.196.211
>   211.196.59.69.in-addr.arpa domain name pointer stackoverflow.com.
>   fmark@home:~$ whois stackoverflow.com
>
> Whois Server Version 2.0
>
> Domain names in the .com and .net
>   domains can now be registered with
>   many different competing registrars.
>
> ```
>  <SNIP>
> ```
>
> **> Registrant:    stackoverflow.com llc
>
>   410 Clayton Ave    El Cerrito,
>   California 94530    United States**
>
> ```
>  <SNIP>
> ```

Obviously this isn't hugely accurate, so more sophisticated techniques are allegedly used.

Answer (score 0):

If the geolocation functionality is not a big requirement for your project, you can use something as simple as this:

```
$geotxt='';
$dt=json_decode(@file_get_contents('https://freegeoip.net/json/'.$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']));
if ($dt!=null) $geotxt=$dt->country_name.', '.$dt->region_name.', '.$dt->city;
echo $geotxt;
```

You have to take into account that freegeoip has a limit of 10k request/hour.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the existing databases use an aggregation of data from the international registries ARIN, AFRINIC, ANIC etc as well as user submitted locations. More sophisticated techniques include Topology and Constraints Geolocation.

I run my own API [ipdata.co](https://ipdata.co?utm_campaign=stackoverflow-answer-2574542&utm_medium=answer&utm_source=stackoverflow) that provides several data points including, the country, city, region, lat/long and others.

> This answer uses a 'test' API Key that is very limited and only meant for testing a few calls. [Signup](https://ipdata.co?utm_campaign=stackoverflow-answer-2574542-free-plan-cta&utm_medium=answer&utm_source=stackoverflow) for your own Free API Key and get up to 1500 requests daily for development.

```
php > $data = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://api.ipdata.co/69.59.196.211?api-key=test'),true);
php > echo $data['country_name'];
//United States
php > echo $data['city'];
//Albany
```