# How to redirect different visitors to different sub domains

Tags: php, web-applications

how to redirect different visitors from different countries to different sub domains. like US people - us.yourdomain.com, India - India.yourdomain.com

Comment: Don't make Google's mistake (OK, so I'm in Spain, that doesn't mean I want Google in Spanish or results optimised for people living in Spain, I'm just on holiday).

Comment: possible duplicate of [best way to detect country / location of visitor?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4179000/best-way-to-detect-country-location-of-visitor)

Answer (score 3):

Download MaxMind's GeoIP.dat database from here:

```
http://geolite.maxmind.com/download/geoip/database/GeoLiteCountry/GeoIP.dat.gz Free Version (GeoLiteCountry)
```

Then download geoip.inc from here:

```
http://geolite.maxmind.com/download/geoip/api/php/php-1.11.tar.gz
```

Extract and find geoip.inc file.

Then upload those two files to the same directory where page is located.
Edit php page and use this script inside of it:

```
<?php require_once('geoip.inc');
 $gi = geoip_open('GeoIP.dat', GEOIP_MEMORY_CACHE);
 $country = geoip_country_code_by_addr($gi, $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
 $my_countries = array('us', 'ca', 'gb', 'fr', 'de', 'nl');
 if (!in_array(strtolower($country), $my_countries)){
 header('Location: http://www."ALL"TRAFFICURLGOESHERE.whatever');
 }
 else{
 header('Location: http://www."SELECTEDCOUNTRIES"URLGOESHERE.whatever');
 }
 ?>
```

Simply change the country codes you want to target in the line:

```
$my_countries = array('us', 'ca', 'gb', 'fr', 'de', 'nl');
```

and the URLs for both the targeted traffic and rest traffic where mentioned.

Country Codes can be found here: MaxMind - ISO 3166 Country Codes

Answer (score 1):

Your best option is to make a root page that has all the countries and or languages you want on there and create a cookie that remembers what they chose. That way, they will only see that page once, provided they do not clear cookies.

Answer (score 0):

I want to add to Nirmal's answer that some servers won't work with "Header('location:url')"

I don't know why but this happened to me on siteground

So instead of "header(location....)" I used echo and then the meta refresh method, which is considered a better redirect by seo's, by the way. so full code would be:

```
<?php
$website_root_path=’/path/to/root/’;require($website_root_path . ‘geoip.inc’);
$ip=$_SERVER[‘REMOTE_ADDR’];$gi=geoip_open($website_root_path . ‘GeoIP.dat’, GEOIP_STANDARD);
$country = geoip_country_code_by_addr($gi, $ip);
if ($country == ‘US’) {
}
else { 
    echo ‘<META HTTP-EQUIV=”Refresh” Content=”0; URL=http://non-us.hiboomedia.com”>’;
    exit; 
}
?>
```

In my case I just wanted to redirect anyone who's not from the us to a non-us website. adapt it to your needs ;)