# Autocompleteplus how to detect user language(Real language not browser)?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, api

I'm looking for a way to get a user default language by the country. For example I have windows in english but  still I would like to get my country 2 letter language ("cs")

You can see an example of what I want, In the source code of http://search.conduit.com/ using (Autocompleteplus) as well. This is what I see:

```
  window.language = "en-us";
         window.countryCode = "cz";
         window.suggestBaseUrl = "http://api.autocompleteplus.com/?q=UCM_SEARCH_TERM&l=cs&c=cz&callback=acp_new";
```

You can see the api url has inside "l=cs&c=cz" how did they get this information? I would like to have the same thing I use the same autocompleteplus method just need a way to generate the l=(user true langague)&c=(country code) and performance is important as well. It's autosuggestions for my website search.

Comment: They're probably detecting this based on your IP address, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4179000/best-way-to-detect-country-location-of-visitor

Answer (score 1):

This is Ed from AutoComplete+.  Getting the user country is typically done when using our API through server side implementations.  There are however some open APIs that can assist you.  Regardless, you can use our autocomplete feed without the user country.  Feel free to contact us directly for further info at http://www.autocompleteplus.com

Thanks,
--ed

Comment: that's perfect if your api supports that how should i implement it is there a demo code or documentation?