# How to get city using network location?

Tags: android, networking, location

[image]

I want to get something like the image above. I want to be able to press a button, and grab the city's name only using the location network, NOT GPS.

How would I approach this? What API would I use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a very useful page on the Android Development site:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html

And it talks about the various ways you can ensure to get any location quick and reliable. It talks about how you can use cached network location or wifi-based, if you don't need to use the GPS.

Answer (score 0):

I seen a something like this here.

[Location detecting tecniques for IP addresses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2574542/location-detecting-tecniques-for-ip-addresses)

It look like this type of detection might have a financial burden or a inconsistent/unreliable burden. But in short finding the city name using Ip address is not a built in service that Google provides. Hopes this helps.