# possible to have a different logo shown depending on what area of the world the user is located?

Tags: html, css, ip-address

is it possible to have a website, and have it so that when a user visits a site from the united states, the main logo appears as a jpg.  And then, if another user from Europe visits the site, a different logo jpg appears depending on their location visited?

Comment: Not without something else more dynamic in conjunction with your HTML (PHP, Javascript, etc.)

Comment: Look into something like geoIP for PHP: http://us3.php.net/geoip

Comment: Yes, php. It will be a wordpress site.

Comment: check this: [stackoveflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2574542/location-detecting-tecniques-for-ip-addresses)