# how to prevent a country from accessing my website

Tags: .htaccess, google-analytics

I have a french website and i have a lot of russian visitor (bot ?) and i don't want them in my GA stats.

So first I tried to prevent Russian visitor from accessing my website by htaccess. But still russian visitor ...

Then I tried to allow only French visitor, still with htaccess solution :

```
<Limit GET HEAD POST>
  order deny,allow
  allow from 2.0.0.0/12
  allow from 2.16.2.0/23
  allow from 2.16.9.0/24
  ...
  deny from all
</Limit>
```

Unfortunately I still have russian visitor in my GA. Is that possible ?

I don't know what to do anymore, please bring me light !

Thx

Comment: You can give a try on this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2574542/location-detecting-tecniques-for-ip-addresses

Comment: @Solano in this post i've found a link to http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/legacy/downloadable/ and with this link http://www.finalwebsites.com/forums/topic/how-to-use-maxmind-geoip-for-websites i succeed to configure it. Wait and see if this solution works !

Comment: maxmind solution doesn't work in my case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your .htaccess solution may be failing to filter out these spam results because the Russian hits in question may not be "real".

Check out this article on referral spam: http://www.analyticsedge.com/2014/12/removing-referral-spam-google-analytics/

There is a nice description of "ghost referrals" that directly manipulate GA to post fake page views by using random GA numbers (you may even find that your GA number appears in the referral link for these hits when you view acquisition > all traffic > referrals).

Unfortunately, if this is the case then .htaccess will not do anything for you and you will need to use GA filters to filter out these results going forward.

Comment: yes, i use GA filters : country Russia and it seems to be working.