# How to find geographical location in the browser without calls over the Web

Tags: javascript, geolocation

I have a web application that wants you to set a time zone and a geographical location (country) for yourself. I want to provide the user with a guess without using a remote API call, as my system might not have access to the Internet.

I have found a JS snippet that proposes a reasonable timezone guess based on time and dst settings from the user's browser. I would like to have a basic guessing system (say, a small IP -> country database) that can work offline.

¿Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the phrase "client side geolocation" may help you during some Googling. See http://html5demos.com/geo for an HTML5 demo which is done *by* the browser. I'm pretty sure solutions such as [Need a client side API for determing geo location of IP addresses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2244989/need-a-client-side-api-for-determing-geo-location-of-ip-addresses) would require either server communications or a large downloading of the geolocation database to the client.